# Add UIVIew as SubView to right bottom of window iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Currently I've got a `UIView` of size 100px wide by 40px high. If I add it using

`[self.view addSubView:buttonsView];`

it adds this small UIVIew to the top left of my iPhone's screen.

Is there any way to make it add to the bottom right instead?

Comment: or use the autoresizingMask .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258216/position-a-uiview-relative-to-the-bottom-of-the-parent-view

Comment: and for the annoying arithmetic .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258216/position-a-uiview-relative-to-the-bottom-of-the-parent-view/20287309#20287309

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before adding the buttonView, set its "frame" property:

One way:

```
buttonsView.frame = CGRectMake( 
 self.view.frame.size.width - buttonsView.frame.size.width,
 self.view.frame.size.height - buttonsView.frame.size.height,
 buttonsView.frame.size.width,
 buttonsView.frame.size.height );
```