# Position a UIView relative to the bottom of the parent view?

Tags: iphone, ios, layout, uiview, ios4

How can I align a UIView to the bottom of the parent so that the Y coordinate of the frame is relative to the bottom of the screen instead of the top?

This would be the equivalent to setting the .bottom property in HTML.

This is because I want to make sure my view is always at the bottom of window regardless of the height of the parent.

Comment: It's quite simple if you know the dimension of your subview (for example 768, 50). Inside your superview, within `viewDidLoad` method, for example, you can add your subview like the following: `[superView addSubview:subView]`. Where your subview is instantieted as follow: `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, superview.bounds.height - 50, 768, 50)]`. P.S check for the right code in the documentation.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Once you have initially positioned the view by setting its `frame` property, adjust its `autoresizingMask` to include `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`. That will keep it anchored to the bottom of its superview.

Comment: Almost worked, had to set the view's frame Y coordinate to a negative number to pull the view up from the bottom.

Comment: Amazingly simple and still works perfectly in iOS 8.

Comment: In iOS 8, you can use Auto Layout, which is a much better way of expressing this need, but is way beyond the scope of this answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the autoresizing mask values on the Sizing pane in XIB or Storyboard editor.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    bottomButton.Alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Bottom;          
}
```