# How can I fix a UIView to the bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am developing an app with auto layout turned off and default setting to the Iphone 5. Now I have a UIView at the bottom of the screen, when I switch between the size options in IB the UIView correctly moves up to fix itself to the bottom of the screen. When however I test on my IPhone 4 or the simulator it doesn't move up, instead it gets cutoff.

How can I make it so that the UIView at the bottom of the app gets shunted upwards for the smaller IPhone 4?

See the following example

[image]

[image]

I basically want the white box to be shunted upwards to fill the gap underneath the grey box.

***Update***

In terms of the view hierarchy, there is a containing view and then the white section that you see is a simple UIView (white background) with a scroll view inside. The project is fairly new so the setup is very simple and there is no code to position any of the UIViews.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? or AutoresizingMask?

Comment: I turned AutoLayout off, I am using the autosizing feature

Comment: @IconicDigital, your 4-inch and 3.5-inch images are not comparing like-for-like... see my updated answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to get the Y coord, get the screen height, subtract any UI elements above the main view (like status bar) and subtract the height of the UIView you are placing. For example:

```
float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height - myView.frame.size.height;
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height)];
```

---

Here's a really typical full example...2013...this works nicely in a UITableViewController with a nav bar at top, and you are **not** using autolayout.

[Position a UIView relative to the bottom of the parent view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258216/position-a-uiview-relative-to-the-bottom-of-the-parent-view/20287309#20287309)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

You should have your springs and struts (Autosizing mask) set something like this...

[image]

Then the view will maintain it's distance from the foot of the screen.

*update*

In your comment, you say you have this set correctly yet the view is still pushed down. However, the images in your question do not compare like-with-like. In the 4-inch version your view seems to be scrolled up above the top of the screen, which is not the case with the 3.5-inch version. I suspect therein lies the cause (or is that just b/c you had to scroll your 4-inch up to fit the problem onscreen?) ... can you check and maybe update your question with more detail about your view hierarchy.

Comment: Hi, I have it setup like that but it is still ignoring it.

Comment: @IconicDigital - ok then that is weird. Have you any code making/setting frame parameters on views, or anything else like that?

Comment: Funny thing is if I switch between the sizes in IB it moves it fine. If you then test it in the simulator is cuts it off.

Comment: @IconicDigital, that's why you need to give us more info about your view hierarchy - especially are you setting _any_ frame info in code? This would not show up in IB but would show up in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

With AutoLayout off where you place the view on the screen is a fixed value. To have this auto adjust you need some code. You will need to use a `autoresizingMask`. Here is an example of using autoresizingMask/

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to select your view, then go to Editor -> Pin -> Bottom Space to SuperView. This option fixes your view to the bottom of the container view, regardless of the device resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @Joel answer, for iOS 7 we dont need to subtract the statusBar height.

```
float y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - myView.frame.size.height;
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height)];
```